# How Can I Get Files And Folders Of A Special Website Like IDM Grabber In C#

Tags: c#, http, c#-4.0, download

*If you have worked with IDM(Internet Download Manager) this has a item named Grabber that searches in a special web site and get the files and folders of that website and you can download them using IDM.*

I would like to do something similar in C#. I would like to download html web pages and extract links from those pages. I would also like to detect directories and attempt to search their contents - possibly parsing "Index Of" directory listing pages.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Help you with what exactly? As it stands, your question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: @Oded:Now I want to have a feature like this in my program

Comment: Yes, but you didn't ask a specific programming question. Which part are you having difficulties with, code examples etc. Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex` or use the `HtmlAgilityPack` (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the website and find links to files. You may need to check the extension of the file. Ie. Only parse links that end in `.zip|.exe|.msi|.rar|.png|.pdf|.gif|.jpg|.jpeg`.

Comment: How can I do it in HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Load the page. Parse the page. Use Xpath to find all `anchor` links. Get the href and then parse the href.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a "Web Spider" to do this and published the [source code over at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaWebSpider.aspx).

If you want to do it as an end-user, I found out the the free [Httrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) works pretty well.